# Making event handler complete the work before triggering the next time

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling

I am using an API in which there is an in-built event handler that triggers every time something happens. I believe it is being triggered asynchronously.

```
void someEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = len; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(array[i]))
        {
            // Doing something
            // Deleting key from the dictionary (previously stored) and then doing some processing
            // Now adding another key to the dictionary
            // also updating array[i] = new key
        }
        else
        {
            // if key not found I am doing some other processing
        }
    }
}
```

This event handler is being triggered twice within microseconds and while it is being triggered for the first time I can see that it entered if statement for i = 1 which is correct and but for the second time it is triggered (within microseconds) it entered else part with i = 1, which is wrong. Technically value of i should be 0 for second time since array[1] contains a key now (when it triggered the first time). I believe this is because of asynchronous behavior. Although I am not sure about it. Can any one please tell the reason why is it so? Also I am using lock thinking that it is happening due to asynchronous behavior. But its not working. Is there a better way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing apparent asynchronously about the posted code. I suspect you mean that the code is called *concurrently*. From your description of your method it sounds like it is not thread safe, and in that case you need to protect it by a lock:

```
void someEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock(dictionary){
        ...
    }
}
```

If this do not help, ensure that there is no other concurrent access to the dictionary, and if there are, you need to lock the dictionary in all places where it is used. Or use a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-7.0).

Writing some unit tests might help reproduce issues. Just start a bunch of tasks that call your code concurrently. While this can confirm that your code is not thread safe, *it cannot prove it is thread safe*.

However, thread safety is a complicated subject. And not all problems are solved by adding locks. There is no easy way to determine if some piece of code is thread safe, and mistakes can be costly. There are some practices, like using immutable data and pure methods, that help. But fundamentally you need to know a fair bit about thread safety if you are going to attempt any kind of multi threaded code. This is not an area where trial and error is appropriate.